# Do @Session(roles=..) for method replace or append to the class roles?

Tags: java, rest, session, roles, java-web-start

If I am writing an API interface class, with imports:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
```

When I am writing an annotation before a class:

```
@Session(roles = { Role.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR })
```

And another one before a method:

```
@Session(roles = { Role.ROLE_USER })
```

*Will the API method have access by **both** roles, or only by user one?*

I have googled for examples, and I see many contradictory ones. And no explanations.